# $centerSphere is not returning any thing MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

** excuse me if there is issues in the question this the first time for me to post a quistion here
**
iam trying to get the bootcamps by the location, iam using the geocoder package to get the location details such as the longtiude and the latitude from the address that the user provide, it works right and i get the location details. but when i use the $centerSphere function to get the bootcamps, the request is made and give me 200 status but it gives me an empty array of bootcamps, i checked every thing and it works correctly except the $centerSphare function i think the problem is in it, so what can i do now to fix this

> here is the model schema

```js
location: {
        // GeoJSON point
        type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point']
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
            index: '2dsphere'
        },
        formattedAddress: String,
        street: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        zipcode: String,
        country: String
    }
```

> and this is the controlers

```js
exports.getBootcampsInRadius = asyncHandler( async (req , res , next) => {
    const { zipcode, distance } = req.params;

    // Get lat/lng from geocoder
    const loc = await geocoder.geocode(zipcode);
    const lat = loc[0].latitude;
    const lng = loc[0].longitude;

    // Calc radius using uadiand 
    // Divide dist by radius of Earth
    // Earth radius = 3,963 mi / 6,376 km
    const radius = distance / 3963.2;

    const bootcamps = await Bootcamp.find({
        location: {
            $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ lng, lat ], radius ] }
        }
    });

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        count: bootcamps.length,
        data: bootcamps
    });
});
```

> it keeps give me this result

```
{
"success": true,
"count": 0,
"data": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your database if every document has its own **coordinates** for MongoDB to search on.

**Example *(inside a document)***:

```
location: Object
   type: "Point"
   coordinates: Array
      0: -50
      1: 50
```

[image: screenshot inside a document with coordinates]

Answer (score 0):

Check inside db, your type property inside document should be "Point", pascal case.